# RefreshRibbon and Invalidate error

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, ribbon

I have my xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="CallBackOnLoad">
```

and

```
 button id"ThisButton".......getVisible="GetVisible"
```

In one module

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public gobjRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public bolVisible As Boolean

Public Function GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
'some logic
end function
```

Separate Module

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public gobjRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public bolVisible As Boolean

Public Sub globalInit()
    If gobjRibbon Is Nothing Then Call CallbackOnLoad
End Sub

Sub CallbackOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set gobjRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Public Function RefreshRibbon()
    gobjRibbon.Invalidate
End Function
```

Sometimes I'll get 'Object or with block varialbe not set" on the Invalidate, sometimes I don't.  If I managed to get pass the invalidate it's supposed to refresh the ribbon which calls the GetVisible function but instead I get an error for each of my buttons GetVisible stating my form can't find the GetVisible function.  I'm about to pull my hair out but I'm already bald.  Any suggestions?  Everything seems to be place.

edit: I'll add that the visibility logic is being determined by who's logged in to a particular form.  That form loads first, user logs in and a call to the RefreshRibbon is initiated.

edit:  I think I figured out the first error.  This only happens if I'm stepping through the code and since the ribbon has an OnLoad event assigned to it...something something something

Comment: As far as I know, `'Object or with block varialbe not set" on the Invalidate` this error occurs when another error has preceded. Then any global variables (in this case gobjRibbon) are unset. I am quite confident that you only get one chance to initialize your ribbon variable and that's on MS Access startup. After that, I have found absolutely no way to reference it and assign it to a variable. If anyone can prove me wrong, please do :)

Comment: I was ablel to take of this error but thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong and if I am I'll be happy to delete my answer.

Ribbons get loaded when Access starts. That's the only time their Load event fires.

As to controlling when/if the ribbon is displayed, I think you should be able to do this through the form's RibbonName Property. I was able to add a ribbon name to my Form during the Form's open event.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel as Integer)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to load the ribbon?", vbYesNo, "Um...") = vbYes Then
        Me.RibbonName = "MyCustomRibbon"
    End If
End Sub
```